# When would the Windows environment variable be HOMEPATH=\

Tags: windows, environment-variables

```
set HOME
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\
USERDOMAIN=user01
USERNAME=user01
USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\user01

Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
```

On the Windows boxes I've tested until now, `USERPROFILE=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

When I originallydecided to go with `HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH`, I read an article that said it was the safest way to go.

What would be causing `HOMEPATH` to be `/`?

If commands are needed to be executed on this machine, please put them in the form of a batch file.  Thank you.

Comment: It looks to me like your install of Windows is setup in a non standard way.  All three Windows ( XP x2 and 7) in my home show the standard config.  Home at the root of c: seems dangerous to me.

Comment: While having the home reflect the root of the share isn't *typical*, it's not necessarily improperly configured. Applications should not rely on those environment variables. I can't think of any reason (off of the top of my head) why having home at the root of C: would be dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HOMEPATH can be set to an equivalent of either %USERPROFILE% or the root of %HOMEDRIVE%. For scripts that you're writing on DOS/CMD on modern versions of windows (XP/Vista), you should use %USERPROFILE%.

That said, if you're writing an application (or vbs, etc), get the shell folders list from windows, as it is (generally) more accurate/reliable than %userprofile%.

Comment: I found another circumstance where the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH variables do not exist.  I have not been able to reproduce problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `USERPROFILE` is NOT identical to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

In short words:

1. With roaming profiles: HOMEPATH is the roaming location and USERPROFILE is the local location (See [git-wrapper.c](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MINGW-packages/blob/main/mingw-w64-git/git-wrapper.c#L132-L163))
2. e.g.  when you use secondary logons `run as`, HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH will not be refresh, and HOMEPATH will always be `\Windows\system32` for each user (See [meaning-variables-homedrive-homepath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36392591/2377961) why this happens)

To read the full context check issue [git-for-windows#2709](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2709#issuecomment-649547803)

**EDIT:** I found out that HOPMEPATH will be `\` when you are useing network profiles, like you can read in [how-do-i-change-homedrive-homepath-and-homeshare-in-windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/246731/how-do-i-change-homedrive-homepath-and-homeshare-in-windows-xp)